# How do I generate a list like this

Tags: haskell

suppose I have the following list of list

```
a = [[1 2]  
     [4 2]
     [7 3]]
```

I want to generate a list like this

```
makeRow :: [[Int]] -> [Int]

  0 1 2  3 4 5  6 7 8 9  
[-1 0 0 -1 0 0 -1 0 0 0]
```

So the list will have 2 0s starting at index 1, 2 0s starting at index 4, and 3 more 0s starting at index 7.  Place that doesn't have 0s is default to -1

Comment: What is your question specifically? Are you asking for us to write the code for you, or just general tips on the implementation of something like what you describe?

Comment: My intuition tells me I should use list comprehension, but cant get the filter down.

Comment: I think this is a decent question because it is (at first glance) hard code to write functionally. Assuming the 0-chunks can overlap and come in any order...

Comment: 0 chunk is guaranteed to not overlap

Comment: Out of curiosity, did this question come from somewhere, or are you just making up little problems for yourself? Also, is it guaranteed that the input will be ordered. That is, would  `[[1 2], [7 3], [4 2]]` be a valid input list?

Comment: @MatrixFrog it small section of larger homework problem.  For now, assume the input will be ordered.  SO [[1 2], [7 3], [4 2]] is not a valid input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you can definitely use list comprehension but here's a stab at it without.

```
import Data.List

makeRow :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
makeRow arr = place tabulate length
              where tabulate = foldl' expand [] arr
                    expand st [idx,num] = st++[idx..(idx+num-1)]
                    length = last tabulate

place :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int] 
place rules l = foldr ins [] [0..l]
                where ins i st = if elem i rules then 0:st else (-1):st
```

So makeRow first expands the rules into a list of indexes that should be set to -1. Then, place loops over every index and if it is in our expanded list of rules, it adds a 0, otherwise it adds a -1.

```
*Main> makeRow [[1,2],[4,2],[7,3]]
[-1,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,0]
```

I'd love to see someone try this in a list comprehension. I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this but this will get the job done. I'll leave it up as an exercise to OP to figure out how to write this less kludgily.

(One-liner version)

```
import Data.List

makeRow :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
makeRow arr = [if any (\[i,n] -> elem a [i..(i+n-1)]) arr 
               then 0 else -1 | a <- [0..((sum $ last arr)-1)] ]
```

I maintain that trading readability for tricks like making this function a one-liner is not a great practice. However, I'm still holding out hope that a real wizard will show me an even more concise method.

Comment: meh, was looking for a one liner

Comment: Updated answer but I think the first is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This one is shorter and probably easier to comprehend. Still no list comprehension though. ;-)

```
makeRow = go 0
  where go _ [] = []
        go i ([j,n]:xs) = replicate (j-i) (-1) ++ replicate n 0 ++ go (j+n) xs
```

You need to add error checking and input sanitizing if there is no guarantee that the desired fields will not overlap or that they are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to produce such a list in a non-Haskell language? Depending on what you do it can be fairly straightfoward to convert a while loop to a tail recursive function. (The result might not be perfectly idiomatic in most cases but knowing how to do these conversions is very useful)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not the most concise method, but I find this extremely readable and straightforward

```
makeRow :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
makeRow []            = []
makeRow ([0,n]:pairs) = replicate n 0 ++ makeRow (map (decrementBy n) pairs)
makeRow pairs         =            -1 :  makeRow (map (decrementBy 1) pairs)
    where decrementBy n [x,y] = [x-n,y]
```